# Articles in description of figures

Tags: articles

With a picture of a presentation that contains an arrow pointing from a text, for instance, "probability", is the label in the capture "The probability" or "Probability"?

[image: Probability]

Comment: Thank you. Thus, for the example above it is "Probability".

Comment: While adding the article doesn't offend rules of grammar (below sentence level, these are sparse), it would give an unnatural, probably unprofessional feel. You might consider briefly specifying _what the probability refers to_ ('Probability of Stromboli erupting within next 10 years' etc).

Comment: Thank you, I mean simple words, for instance, in presentations. E.g. 'Result' and an arrow aiming to the resulting number.